# Tic Tac Toe game (Python, tkinter). Where is the bug?

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't find the problem in the code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Tic Tac Toe")

click = True

def play(buttons):
    buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9]
    global click

    if buttons["text"] == " " and click == True:
        buttons["text"] = "X"
        click = False
    elif buttons["text"] == " " and click == False:
        buttons['text'] = "O"
        click = False

    elif (button1["text"] == "X" and button2["text"] == "X" and button3["text"] == "X" or
        button4["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" or
        button7["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or
        button1["text"] == "X" and button4["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X" or
        button2["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" or
        button3["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or
        button1["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or
        button3["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X"):
        answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('X Player wins!!!', 'Do you want to play again')

    elif (button1["text"] == "O" and button2["text"] == "O" and button3["text"] == "O" or
        button4["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" or
        button7["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or
        button1["text"] == "O" and button4["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O" or
        button2["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" or
        button3["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or
        button1["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or
        button3["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O"):
        answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('X Player wins!!!', 'Do you want to play again')

buttons = StringVar()

button1 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button1))
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S+N+E+W)

button2 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button2))
button2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=S+N+E+W)

button3 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button3))
button3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=S+N+E+W)

button4 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button4))
button4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=S+N+E+W)

button5 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=("Times 26 bold"), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button5))
button5.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=S+N+E+W)

button6 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button6))
button6.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=S+N+E+W)

button7 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button7))
button7.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=S+N+E+W)

button8 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button8))
button8.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=S+N+E+W)

button9 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button9))
button9.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=S+N+E+W)


tk.mainloop()
```

If you know where is the problem or how to write the code correctly, please send it to me!

Comment: Pleas describe what's not working.

Comment: Don't use the same name for multiple things. `buttons` is both a list and a `StringVar`.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't just copy the code at the end, [@Abdelrahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7680166/abdelrahman-orief). If you do, you won't learn from your mistakes.

There were a few issues. Firstly, the function `play` takes an argument `buttons`. This argument is pointless, as it is immediately overwritten by this line:

```
buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9]
```

This means that rather than `buttons` being set to the button that was just clicked, it is a list of all the buttons. Thus, when `buttons["text"]` is called, you get a `TypeError`, for using a string as an index when it needs an integer.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Genora51\Desktop\tictactoe.py", line 42, in <lambda>
    button1 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button1))
  File "C:\Users\Genora51\Desktop\tictactoe.py", line 13, in play
    if buttons["text"] == " " and click == True:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

So I removed that line that overwrites `buttons` and renamed the argument to `button` for clarity (it will only be one button). The long `if`-statements still stand because the buttons are global variables.

```
def play(button):
    global click, tk

    if button["text"] == " " and click == True:
        button["text"] = "X"
        click = False
    elif button["text"] == " " and click == False:
        button['text'] = "O"
        click = False
```

I also noticed that on the last line of that `elif`, `click` was still being set to `False`. So I changed that to set it to `True`, allowing for players to alternate between X-O-X-O, rather than X-O-O-O...

```
elif (button1["text"] == "X"...
```

Another problem was that this was an `elif` statement, so it was never reached (the first `if` and `elif` statements got there first). That was changed to an `if`. Now, the game mechanic largely worked, and the code picked up on an endgame. But the `messagebox.askquestion` didn't do anything. So I placed the main body of the code in a new function, `start`, and added a bit of code, such that when the player chose, it would close the main window, and if they wanted to play again, it would create a new window.

```
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('X Player wins!!!', 'Do you want to play again')
    tk.destroy()
    if answer == 'yes': start()
```

I finally removed a few extra bits of unnecessary code (e.g. `buttons = StringVar()`), to produce this.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

click = True
tk = None
def start():
    global tk
    tk = Tk()
    tk.title("Tic Tac Toe")

    def play(button):
        global click, tk

        if button["text"] == " " and click:
            button["text"] = "X"
            click = False
        elif button["text"] == " ":
            button['text'] = "O"
            click = True

        if (button1["text"] == "X" and button2["text"] == "X" and button3["text"] == "X" or
            button4["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" or
            button7["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or
            button1["text"] == "X" and button4["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X" or
            button2["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" or
            button3["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or
            button1["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or
            button3["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X"):
            answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('X Player wins!!!', 'Do you want to play again')
            tk.destroy()
            if answer == 'yes': start()
            
        elif (button1["text"] == "O" and button2["text"] == "O" and button3["text"] == "O" or
            button4["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" or
            button7["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or
            button1["text"] == "O" and button4["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O" or
            button2["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" or
            button3["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or
            button1["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or
            button3["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O"):
            answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('O Player wins!!!', 'Do you want to play again')
            tk.destroy()
            if answer == 'yes': start()

    button1 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button1))
    button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S+N+E+W)

    button2 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button2))
    button2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=S+N+E+W)

    button3 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button3))
    button3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=S+N+E+W)

    button4 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button4))
    button4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=S+N+E+W)

    button5 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=("Times 26 bold"), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button5))
    button5.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=S+N+E+W)

    button6 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button6))
    button6.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=S+N+E+W)

    button7 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button7))
    button7.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=S+N+E+W)

    button8 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button8))
    button8.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=S+N+E+W)

    button9 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button9))
    button9.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=S+N+E+W)


    tk.mainloop()

start()
```

However, be aware that the only reason I did any of this was because I am in a *very* good mood today. Next time you have a problem, make sure to read the `Traceback` and gather what you can. Look up the error and try to solve it based on what's already on the internet, rather than asking other altruistic programmers to solve your problems for you, for free. At least post the errors that are already there, so we know what your problem is at the outset, and be clear about what you want solved. In future, try to solve a problem your own way first, because you might not be nearly as lucky the next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter.messagebox

click = True

tk = None

def start():

    global tk

    tk = Tk()

    tk.title("Game-Tic Tac Toe:Two Player")



    def play(button):

        global click, tk



        if button["text"] == " " and click:

            button["text"] = "X"

            click = False

        elif button["text"] == " ":

            button['text'] = "O"

            click = True



        if (button1["text"] == "X" and button2["text"] == "X" and button3["text"] == "X" or

            button4["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" or

            button7["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or

            button1["text"] == "X" and button4["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X" or

            button2["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button8["text"] == "X" or

            button3["text"] == "X" and button6["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or

            button1["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button9["text"] == "X" or

            button3["text"] == "X" and button5["text"] == "X" and button7["text"] == "X"):

            answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('X Player wins!!!', 'Do you want to play again')

            tk.destroy()

            if answer == 'yes': start()



        elif (button1["text"] == "O" and button2["text"] == "O" and button3["text"] == "O" or

            button4["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" or

            button7["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or

            button1["text"] == "O" and button4["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O" or

            button2["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button8["text"] == "O" or

            button3["text"] == "O" and button6["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or

            button1["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button9["text"] == "O" or

            button3["text"] == "O" and button5["text"] == "O" and button7["text"] == "O"):

            answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('O Player wins!!!', 'Do you want to play again')

            tk.destroy()

            if answer == 'yes': start()



    button1 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button1))

    button1.grid(row=1, column=0)



    button2 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button2))

    button2.grid(row=1, column=1)



    button3 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button3))

    button3.grid(row=1, column=2)



    button4 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button4))

    button4.grid(row=2, column=0)



    button5 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=("Times 26 bold"), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button5))

    button5.grid(row=2, column=1)



    button6 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button6))

    button6.grid(row=2, column=2)



    button7 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button7))

    button7.grid(row=3, column=0)



    button8 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button8))

    button8.grid(row=3, column=1)



    button9 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=('Times 26 bold'), height=4, width=8, command=lambda:play(button9))

    button9.grid(row=3, column=2)
    tk.mainloop()
start()
```